# i cant get "chmod +x /usr/bin/katoolin" to work. what should i do?

Tags: 14.04, permissions

im done with

```
git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git  && cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin
```

and the next step is

```
chmod +x  /usr/bin/katoolin
```

after that i get this error

```
chmod: cannot access ‘/usr/bin/katoolin’: No such file or directory
```

what now?

Comment: did you try adding `sudo` before `chmod`?

Comment: The instructions do say `sudo su` first.

Comment: i've done that obviously.

Comment: It's not obvious. Have you shown to us anywhere you did that command? At any rate, what was the output of the `git clone` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy a file into `/usr/bin` you need `sudo` rights

```
sudo cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin
```

---

Why? Thats why:

Run `stat /usr/bin/` and you will see something like this

```
  File: ‘/usr/bin/’
  Size: 135168      Blocks: 272        IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 1966082     Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-11-26 10:43:50.400084826 +0100
Modify: 2015-11-26 10:41:18.240590816 +0100
Change: 2015-11-26 10:41:18.240590816 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Means, only the `root` user has write access for that folder, not the group `root` and all others also not.

Comment: okay. so i need to do 

`sudo cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin`

and then 

`sudo chmod +x  /usr/bin/katoolin`

right?